# Double Discontinuity In CFT

Tags: quantum-field-theory, operators, conformal-field-theory, commutator, correlation-functions

In the paper [Analyticity in Spin in Conformal Theories](https://arxiv.org/abs/1703.00278) Simon defines the double discontinuity as the commutator squared in (2.15):
$$\text{dDisc}\mathcal{G}\left(\rho,\overline{\rho}\right)=\left\langle \left[O_{2}\left(-1\right),O_{3}\left(-\rho\right)\right]\left[O_{1}\left(1\right),O_{4}\left(\rho\right)\right]\right\rangle \qquad\left(2.15\right)$$
What I want to obtain is the expression in (2.16) for unequal scaling dimensions:
$$\text{dDisc}\mathcal{G}\left(\rho,\overline{\rho}\right)=\cos\left(\pi\left(a+b\right)\right)\mathcal{G}_{E}\left(\rho,\overline{\rho}\right)-\frac{1}{2}e^{i\pi\left(a+b\right)}\mathcal{G}\left(\rho,\overline{\rho}-i0\right)-\frac{1}{2}e^{-i\pi\left(a+b\right)}\mathcal{G}\left(\rho,\overline{\rho}+i0\right)\qquad\left(2.16\right)$$
From what I understand only the $x_{14}^{2}$ (from (2.1)) should get phase when going into the light cone.
$$\left\langle \mathcal{O}_{1}\left(x_{1}\right)\mathcal{O}_{2}\left(x_{2}\right)\mathcal{O}_{3}\left(x_{3}\right)\mathcal{O}_{4}\left(x_{4}\right)\right\rangle =\left(\frac{x_{14}^{2}}{x_{24}^{2}}\right)^{a}\left(\frac{x_{14}^{2}}{x_{13}^{2}}\right)^{b}\frac{\mathcal{G}\left(\rho,\overline{\rho}\right)}{x_{12}^{\Delta_{1}+\Delta_{2}}x_{34}^{\Delta_{3}+\Delta_{4}}}\quad\left(2.1\right)$$
But from my calculation I have the Euclidean correlator minus the Lorentzian correlator. I end up with the same expression in (2.16) but with no cosine.
What boggles me is that in the paper he says that he multiplies by the difference in the prefactor of $\mathcal{G}\left(\rho,\overline{\rho}\right)$ in taking it both from either direction. Coming from here:
$$\text{dDisc}\mathcal{G}\left(\rho,\overline{\rho}\right)=\frac{1}{2}e^{i\pi\left(a+b\right)}\left(\mathcal{G}_{E}\left(\rho,\overline{\rho}\right)-\mathcal{G}_{E}\left(\rho,\overline{\rho}-i0\right)\right)+\frac{1}{2}e^{-i\pi\left(a+b\right)}\left(\mathcal{G}_{E}\left(\rho,\overline{\rho}\right)-\mathcal{G}_{E}\left(\rho,\overline{\rho}+i0\right)\right)$$
But why is it not
$$\text{dDisc}\mathcal{G}\left(\rho,\overline{\rho}\right)=\frac{1}{2}\left(\mathcal{G}_{E}\left(\rho,\overline{\rho}\right)-e^{i\pi\left(a+b\right)}\mathcal{G}_{E}\left(\rho,\overline{\rho}-i0\right)\right)+\frac{1}{2}\left(\mathcal{G}_{E}\left(\rho,\overline{\rho}\right)-e^{-i\pi\left(a+b\right)}\mathcal{G}_{E}\left(\rho,\overline{\rho}+i0\right)\right)$$
What is the mistake in my logic here, shouldn't the Euclidean 4-point function stay the same?